# How to remove annotations that are created in a for loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, annotations, mkmapview

I hope you can help me out.  I'm working on some homework for school, and we have to create a project that takes an array of objects and create map annotations from those objects on a map.  My objects have two values, one being an NSString  *title, and the other a cllocationcoordinate2d called coord.  I have a for loop populating the map annotations on my map view, taking in those objects from the array.

My question is this:  for my assignment, I'm supposed to have an option to delete certain objects from my array, and have the map view remove those deleted objects from the annotations.  I am NOT supposed to clear all annotations and repopulate them sans the deleted objects.  In other words, I'm wondering if there's a way to pick a certain annotation created in a for loop from outside of that method.  Would I need to create a custom id argument in my annotation object?

I'd paste in code, but I'm not exactly sure what you would need to see.  Also, I apologize if this question is vague or confusing; I've never actually used this site before, nor have I really had to come to any one with questions.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code,

```
NSMutableArray *annotationsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for (int i = 0; i < [mapView.annotations count]; i++) {

    NSString *anonotationTitle = [[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i] title];

    if([annotationTitle isEqualToString:@"titleToDelete"]){
        [annotationsToRemove addObject:[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

 }

 [mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove];
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just create a second instance of the annotation, one that's stored in the myAnnotations array but not actually put on the map?

Comment: Advantage of this is, you can iterate through the secondary annotation array, get the annotation you want to delete (may be checking the annotation title), then remove that annotation from your map.

Comment: I have a property set for title in my custom annotation class.  Is there any way to grab an annotation from the mapview.annotations array using that title I created?

Comment: This is the init I used for the annotation class, btw.

//Custom init function
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)text coord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;

Comment: I changed the code, at this line if([annotationTitle isEqualToString:@""]) , give your annotation title you want to delete. isEqualToString:@"titleToDelete"

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of that, my only issue now is scope.  I have it created in a for loop nested inside of viewDidLoad.  How would I access that specific annotation outside of viewDidLoad?  I know that mapview has a property of annotations that returns an array of all the annotations created, and I know that with nsarray you can grab objectAtIndex: that takes an NSIndexPath as an argument...

I think I'm just confusing myself at this point lol.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will look into this a bit more tomorrow

Comment: You just need to know the title of the annotation you are going to delete, I'm not clear why you need the annotation you created in the loop, bcoz you can access all the annotations you added to the mapview by calling mapview.annoations

Comment: I should have specified that this is all done on separate view controllers.  Lol.  The delete from array option is done on the first view, and the map shows up on the second

Comment: Ok, map shows up on the second vc, then how that vc know the annotations to add to the map ? do you pass them from vc1 ?

Comment: I created a singleton that holds an array of custom objects I made, and I access that array in the second vc, which then populates the map view.  Is there a way of keeping track of which objects I deleted and passing that information through to the second vc?  Maybe a second singleton that holds an array of those objects deleted?

Comment: ok, is it ok to delete annotations from the singleton array ? or you can have a secondary singleton array of deleted annos then remove them using `[mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove]`

Comment: I would imagine so.  The only limitation from what I'm reading is that she doesn't want the map to remove all annotations then recreate them on each view load.  So I was thinking if I were to create an array of the objects deleted, load that array in viewDidAppear or willAppear, and run the removeAnnotations function with that array, it would be okay.  Seems legit, right?  This is only my 3rd month of objective c programming, and I really have no other background except some javascript.  My methodology is probably inept, but I'm trying to figure it out as I go lol

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can create custom annotation subclass of `MKAnnotationView`.

For example:

**MyCustomAnnotationView.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class MKAnnotationView;

@interface MyCustomAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* customId;

@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
...
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
    MyCustomAnnotationView* annotationView =
    (MyCustomAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
    annotationView.customId = [dataSource title];
    ....
}
....
```

and remove his from your data source by your `customId` property

Comment: Thank you, I'll research into this a bit more tomorrow c:

Answer (score 0):

How do you intend to select which annotations are being deleted? If it is done via tapping on the accessory control (the little icon on the right of the window that pops up when you tap on a pin) then you can get a reference to the annotation and remove it from the map like this

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    MKAnnotation *tappedAnnotation = view.annotation;
    [mapView removeAnnotation:tappedAnnotation];
}
```

Ref:     [MKMapViewdelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3aannotationView%3acalloutAccessoryControlTapped%3a)